# How do I customize the Terms and Conditions Page on Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, format, terms-and-conditions

When I go to Sales -> Terms and Conditions -> the page to edit my conditions, there is no WYSIWYG to edit the content.
I have a responsive website. If I put unformatted text on the terms and conditions, it overflows the content box on the front office.

[image: unformatted text view]

If I put HTML tags on the back office, it still overflows on the front office and when I inspect the element, I can see that Magento adds a  tag with "plain plain" class.

[image: code tag]

I tried to switch the "show content as" from text to HTML but it does nothing.

How can I customize the terms and conditions ?
How can I do so it doesn't overflow ?
Why is this  tag appearing ?

I have Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: You should just be able to style the code tag so that it doesn't overflow it's parent.

Comment: @Cags I can't do that. If a the code tag with the same class is used on another page that I don't want to change, it will change its style too.

Comment: So use a more specific css selector. However I can't imagine on any page you want a code tag that isn't contained within the layout of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a company developped a module to enable WYSIWYG on the terms and conditions page.

If you're a developer I reckon that shouldn't be hard to develop but as the module is only $17 I guess that's worth a try.

Here's the link: http://codecanyon.net/item/terms-conditions-using-wysiwyg/7182836